# is theme network enabled?

Tags: themes

So I have been looking for something that allows me to get an array of themes that are network enabled (set in the Network Admin > Themes)

There is the field called "allowedthemes" in the wp_options table however, this function is slightly different. It only contains themes that are enabled for that given networked blog as oppose to a global enable... if that makes sense? So it's scope is limited to one blog ID instead of all blogs (this info is set in the Network Admin > Sites > (clicking edit button of desired blog) > Themes).

Anyways, if anyone has any solutions it would be much appreciated :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, using:

```
get_site_option('allowedthemes');
```

as a way to retrieve the list of themes gives me the desired result. Before I was using:

```
get_option('allowedthemes');
```

So, there is at least my answer :) Hope this helps anyone else out there :P